# Reset view to original position after animation

Tags: android

I'm animating a view and I want to reset the view to the original position after animation ended.

This is what I have:

*rl2 is a relativeLayout*

```
rl2.animate().translationX(-60).translationY(117).setDuration(2000);
```

I tried setting this but its not working:

```
rl2.clearAnimation();
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`clearAnimation();` does not reset your animations, it just stops them and removes them from the animation queue. To undo your animations you need to actually undo them. So, for your code block you will need to call `rl2.animate().translationX(0).translationY(0).setDuration(2000);` to move the view back to its original position.

Answer (score 11):

As **@Chris Stillwell** mentioned on his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53214669/1283715), But you can move `View` back to **it's original position** after translation animation by

```
rl2.animate().translationX(0).translationY(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this question was asked long time ago but someone may still look for answer.
I use the `Animation` class for this kind of thing; there is a `setFillAfter` method in this class, so you can set if you want the animation to apply its transformation after it ends.

```
Animation anim = new ScaleAnimation(
            1f, 1f, // Start and end values for the X axis scaling
            1f, 2f, // Start and end values for the Y axis scaling
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0f, // Pivot point of X scaling
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 1f); // Pivot point of Y scaling
anim.setFillAfter(false); // no needed to keep the result of the animation
anim.setDuration(1000);
anim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                    
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

    }
});
gangsterImage.startAnimation(anim);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to **remove** **view** don't use  `animation.removeAllListeners()`, the function cannot continue that's why you will see some error. If you want to disappear a view, use `View.GONE`

in **Kotlin** like this:

```
animation.doOnEnd {
binding.mainLayout.visibility = View.GONE}
```

But by this way you couldn't remove **any animation**! So it' better rest them to the initial position.

```
binding.tvM2.animate().translationX(0f).translationY(0f).rotation(0f)
```

Answer (score 0):

just use `anim.setFillAfter(false);` to reset automatically after animation ends.